# How to create toggle button use python in blender

Tags: add-on, operator

I want to make a toggle button for my custom operator. It works similar to checkbox: once the button is clicked, the operator keeps running until the button gets another click, so will the button itself greyed out. I tried to achieve the grey-out effect by implementing poll() function like this:

```
@classmethod
def poll(cls, context):      
    return context.area.type == 'VIEW_3D' and context.region.type == 'WINDOW' and plane_toggle_flag
```

Every time the button is clicked I want the toggle state to change, so in the operator's **init**(), I write:

```
def __init__(self):   
    plane_toggle_flag=not plane_toggle_flag
```

However, it seems as long as poll() returns false, the **init**() function never get the chance to be called. Any idea how to solve this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10):

1. Create a bool property for Window Manager (it can be for anything, but WM will store our modal operator handler so why not put this in the same place):

   ```
   bpy.types.WindowManager.my_operator_toggle = bpy.props.BoolProperty()
   ```
2. Display it somewhere in the UI with the `toggle` tag on:

   ```
   layout = self.layout
   wm = context.window_manager
   label = "Operator ON" if wm.my_operator_toggle else "Operator OFF"
   layout.prop(wm, 'my_operator_toggle', text=label, toggle=True)
   ```

   It looks like this:

   [image]
3. Create your modal operator (example of basic timer):

   ```
   class SomeModalOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
       bl_idname = "my.operator"
       bl_label = "My Operator"

       def modal(self, context, event):
           print("running")
           if not context.window_manager.my_operator_toggle:
               context.window_manager.event_timer_remove(self._timer)
               return {'FINISHED'}
           return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

       def invoke(self, context, event):
           self._timer = context.window_manager.event_timer_add(0.01, context.window)
           context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
           return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
   ```

   The operator ends itself when the bool property is `False`.
4. Add update function to the bool property that will run the operator:

   ```
   def update_function(self, context):
       if self.my_operator_toggle:
           bpy.ops.my.operator('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
       return

   bpy.types.WindowManager.my_operator_toggle = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
                                                    default = False,
                                                    update = update_function)
   ```

The modal operator is useful when you need to handle user input. For anything else it is better to use [app.handlers](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.app.handlers.html), you can toggle them through bool property in similar fashion.